# Conversion from runes / int8 array to string and vice versa

Tags: arrays, go

I'm porting a library from Java to Go. This library passes all parameters and returns as strings, and I must maintain this way due subsequent steps. I noticed when I cast a rune/int8 array to string and I convert back to rune/int8 array I get different values. I believe that is caused by Unicode characters. Is there a way to get the same values?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {  

    runes := make([]rune,3)
    runes[0] = 97
    runes[1] = -22
    runes[2] = 99

    s := string(runes)

    fmt.Println(runes)  
    for _,r := range(s) {
        fmt.Println(r)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[97 -22 99]
97
65533
99
```

Comment: -22 isn’t a valid rune

Comment: Hi @JimB if I use int8 I get to same result. The point is how to store negative values on a string a get it back.

Comment: Bytes are signed in java so when you print an individual byte you can get something in the range `[-128, 127]`. Go wants uint8, which is `234` in your case.

Comment: Hi @Marc I read in on godocs [link](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#rune) that runes are int32 so the range is ok. I don't understand why I get a diferent values. If in the sample code we change rune to int32 the result will be the same

Comment: ok, the range is fine but you're still giving it a negative number when you're trying to say character value `234`.

Comment: It’s not that -22 isn’t a valid int32 value, it’s that it’s not a valid Unicode character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions to and from a string type
>
> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields
>   a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer. Values
>   outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to
>   "\uFFFD".
>
> Converting a slice of runes to a string type yields a string that is
>   the concatenation of the individual rune values converted to strings.

---

Type `byte` in Go is an alias for type `uint8`.

Type `rune`, a Unicode code point (24-bit unsigned integer), is an alias for `int32`.

Go encodes Unicode code points (`rune`s) as UTF-8 encoded `string`s.

For your example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {

    // Unicode code points are 24-bit unsigned integers
    runes := make([]rune, 3)
    runes[0] = 97
    runes[1] = -22 // invalid Unicode code point
    runes[2] = 99
    fmt.Println(runes)

    // Encode Unicode code points as UTF-8
    // Invalid code points converted to Unicode replacement character (U+FFFD)
    s := string(runes)
    fmt.Println(s)

    // Decode UTF-8 as Unicode code points
    for _, r := range s {
        fmt.Println(r, string(r), r == unicode.ReplacementChar)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/AZUBd2iZp1F

Output:

```
[97 -22 99]
a�c
97 a false
65533 � true
99 c false
```

---

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

[The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/)

Comment: Hi @peterSO thanks for your answer. I'll refactor the libray using int8 arrays instead string.

Comment: @AndréAndrade: Java Strings are encoded as UTF-16 (uint16). "A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html